# How to include Groovy G-String in a Regular Expression

Tags: groovy

I would think there would be many applications for the subject in general.  I can illustrate with an example.  Consider that I want a way to pull out a standard (maven) version from a released jar file.  Regular expressions can be used something like:

```
def m = (~/.*-someUniquePortionHere-(.*)\.jar$/).matcher(jarFileName)
m.matches()
String version = "${m.group(1)}"
```

So the above is over-simplified, but, it works for that UniquePortion - and it helps keep the question simple.   If I want to wrap this in a method that takes the unique portion in as a parameter, can I still use the slashy strings?  I would like to include "$uniquePortion" in the regular expression.   That is, what should the following be?

```
def exampleMethod(String uniquePortion, String jarFileName) {
    // what would this look like here?
    def m = 
    m.matches()
    "${m.group(1)"
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not? Slashy strings ARE GStrings as well. see [link](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Strings+and+GString)

```
def unique = "groovy-all"
def m = (~/.*$unique(.*)\.jar$/).matcher("groovy-all:2.2.jar")
m.matches()
String version = "${m.group(1)}"
assert version == ":2.2"
```

Comment: Hmm.. I must have mistyped something when I tried that because my test wasn't matching. Of course, it is now.

Comment: I must have had a similar problem, because when I tried this it did not work either - this runs perfectly for me though too.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can still concatenate the slashy strings together:

```
def test = "foo-bar-1.4.jar"
def bar = "bar"
def m = test =~ /.*-/ + bar + /-(.*).jar$/
assert m.matches() // true
assert m.group(1) == "1.4" // true
```